# ¿Cómo generar un apk especifico de un build variant?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Tengo una aplicación en donde configuré 2 "productFlavors" (dev y uat) con diferente configuración para cada una, las cuales funcionan perfectamente.
Teniendo como resultado las siguientes variantes:

- devDebug
- devRelease
- uatDebug
- uatRelease

Este es la estructura de mi archivo gradle

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        //configuraciones release
    }

    debug {
        //configuraciones debug
    }
}
productFlavors {
    dev {
       //configuraciones dev
    }
    uat {
       //configuraciones uat
    }
}
```

El problema es al generar apk, muchas veces sólo necesito generar la versión release de la configuración uat "uatRelease" pero actualmente me genera las 4 versiones, lo cual aumenta el tiempo para la generación.

En la siguiente imagen muestro la sección y el flujo mediante el cual genero mis apk

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo generar una tarea en gradle de modo que cuando yo quiera genere todas o sólo una variante?

Comment: Hola damazo, sólo una variante te refieres a solo debug o release, ¿cual es el objetivo de esto?

Comment: Así es @Jorgesys quiero generar sólo un apk que tenga la configuración de uat(por ejemplo diferente url del servidor al que realizo consultas) pero no quiero que sea una versión debug por lo tanto necesito generar el apk de la variante  *uatRelease* la cual tiene activo minifyEnabled, proguard entre otras cosas (sería la versión para subir a tienda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logré resolver mi problema de una manera muy sencilla:

Solo deben ejecutar la tarea assemble[tu variante]

Ejemplo:

- assembleUatDebug
- assembleUatRelease

Utilizando las herramientas de android studio, solo tuve que ir a la sección de **Gradle Projects**, abrir el menú **Execute Gradle Task**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto lanza un dialogo, en donde seleccionamos el modulo e ingresamos la tarea que queremos ejecutar, en mi caso `assembleUatDebug`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto te generará solo el apk correspondiente a la variante elegida.

[Aquí la referencia a la documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode)

Comment: Excelente aportación, gracias!